# Proposed tag synonyms for memory-mapped-files

Tags: support

It seems I'm not able to suggest synonyms on SO for tags that I don't have at least a score of 5 on.  Yet, the following tags appear to be synonymous:

- memory-mapped-files
- memory-mapping
- memory-mapped
- memory-map
- memorymapping

The first tag, memory-mapped-files, is the dominant one in terms of questions.

Comment: Note that "memory mapping" can also apply to things that aren't files. For example, [memory-mapped I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O), as opposed to port I/O when communicating with hardware devices.

Comment: That is true.  Moreover, one may misidentify a diagram of memory allocation as memory mapping.  Nonetheless, it seems most questions with these tags refer to memory mapped files.  Some questions even use multiple synonymous tags.  :(

Comment: Wouldn't the proper action then be to _correct_ the tags; not create synonyms?

Comment: @Flimzy: Who's to handle this when new questions arrive and are given such tags?  I think that's the point of synonyms, so that manual retagging is unnecessary.

Comment: @Iterator: Yes, that's the point of synonyms, when the synonyms are completely unambiguous. But, IMHO, just because one tag is often/always misused the same way is not a good reason to make it a synonym.